# pprintをcsv出力する方法について

Tags: python, python3, csv

python初心者です。
今、以下のようなデータを

```
[{'target': 0.7784212030131844, 'params': {'max_features': 0.930055846603754, 'min_samples_split': 15.28549923074499, 'n_estimators': 166.1393782636472}}, {'target': 0.7785257751009637, 'params': {'max_features': 0.8211760874650731, 'min_samples_split': 16.400614250497348, 'n_estimators': 111.92312397601592}}, {'target': 0.776748024491158, 'params': {'max_features': 0.8527202619237652, 'min_samples_split': 10.276640212585447, 'n_estimators': 116.17540832901375}}, {'target': 0.7806172465875361, 'params': {'max_features': 0.29610611942435106, 'min_samples_split': 19.14282946636424, 'n_estimators': 67.72864397106717}}, {'target': 0.7804996097807776, 'params': {'max_features': 0.22739455976528197, 'min_samples_split': 15.042813808805764, 'n_estimators': 119.9583310838621}}, {'target': 0.7789571409861411, 'params': {'max_features': 0.9341048879929642, 'min_samples_split': 20.243872075020587, 'n_estimators': 228.1899735138356}}, {'target': 0.7711794688046322, 'params': {'max_features': 0.1937909307963061, 'min_samples_split': 4.557090171066585, 'n_estimators': 78.97987307596247}}, {'target': 0.7802251051028884, 'params': {'max_features': 0.552926909013341, 'min_samples_split': 22.404901421882023, 'n_estimators': 130.17874315815246}}]
```

以下のように、pprintしたデータにおいて（長いので省略形にしています）

```
[{'params': {'max_features': 0.930055846603754,
             'min_samples_split': 15.28549923074499,
             'n_estimators': 166.1393782636472},
  'target': 0.7784212030131844},
 {'params': {'max_features': 0.8211760874650731,
             'min_samples_split': 16.400614250497348,
             'n_estimators': 111.92312397601592},
  'target': 0.7785257751009637},
 {'params': {'max_features': 0.8527202619237652,
             'min_samples_split': 10.276640212585447,
             'n_estimators': 116.17540832901375},
  'target': 0.776748024491158}]
```

csv出力したいのですが、データ成形の方法がわかりません。

'target', 'max_features', 'min_samples_split', 'n_estimators'の計4つを項目として値を出力したいです。どのようにすればよろしいですか？

※pprint以外の出力方法で可能であればそちらでも構いません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下は [csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) を使う方法です。当該のデータは `rev` という変数に格納されているという前提で、ファイル `data.csv` に出力します。また、`lineterminator='\n'` を指定していますので `data.csv` ファイルの改行コードは newline(`0x0a`) になります。`lineterminator='\n'` を指定しない場合、改行コードは `\r\n(0x0d0a)` となりますので Windows OS では必要ないかも知れません。

```py
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
  fields = ['target', 'max_features', 'min_samples_split', 'n_estimators']
  writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fields, lineterminator='\n')
  writer.writeheader()
  for row in rev:
    writer.writerow({fields[0]: row[fields[0]], **row['params']})
```

```sh
$ cat data.csv
target,max_features,min_samples_split,n_estimators
0.7784212030131844,0.930055846603754,15.28549923074499,166.1393782636472
0.7785257751009637,0.8211760874650731,16.400614250497348,111.92312397601592
0.776748024491158,0.8527202619237652,10.276640212585447,116.17540832901375
0.7806172465875361,0.29610611942435106,19.14282946636424,67.72864397106717
0.7804996097807776,0.22739455976528197,15.042813808805764,119.9583310838621
0.7789571409861411,0.9341048879929642,20.243872075020587,228.1899735138356
0.7711794688046322,0.1937909307963061,4.557090171066585,78.97987307596247
0.7802251051028884,0.552926909013341,22.404901421882023,130.17874315815246
```

Comment: 出力の確認ができました。前回に引き続き、大変助かっております。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

その形式だと[pandas.json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)と[pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)が使えるでしょう。

ただし、`pandas.json_normalize`だけだとネストされたデータの項目名が`params.max_features`とか、`.`で接続された長い名前になるので、それを短縮する処理が必要になります。
以下のように出来るでしょう。

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'target': 0.7784212030131844, 'params': {'max_features': 0.930055846603754, 'min_samples_split': 15.28549923074499, 'n_estimators': 166.1393782636472}}, {'target': 0.7785257751009637, 'params': {'max_features': 0.8211760874650731, 'min_samples_split': 16.400614250497348, 'n_estimators': 111.92312397601592}}, {'target': 0.776748024491158, 'params': {'max_features': 0.8527202619237652, 'min_samples_split': 10.276640212585447, 'n_estimators': 116.17540832901375}}, {'target': 0.7806172465875361, 'params': {'max_features': 0.29610611942435106, 'min_samples_split': 19.14282946636424, 'n_estimators': 67.72864397106717}}, {'target': 0.7804996097807776, 'params': {'max_features': 0.22739455976528197, 'min_samples_split': 15.042813808805764, 'n_estimators': 119.9583310838621}}, {'target': 0.7789571409861411, 'params': {'max_features': 0.9341048879929642, 'min_samples_split': 20.243872075020587, 'n_estimators': 228.1899735138356}}, {'target': 0.7711794688046322, 'params': {'max_features': 0.1937909307963061, 'min_samples_split': 4.557090171066585, 'n_estimators': 78.97987307596247}}, {'target': 0.7802251051028884, 'params': {'max_features': 0.552926909013341, 'min_samples_split': 22.404901421882023, 'n_estimators': 130.17874315815246}}]

df = pd.json_normalize(data) #### DataFrame化

#### 項目名の短縮処理
head = []
for s in list(df.columns):
  p = s.rfind('.')
  if p < 0:
    head.append(s)
  else:
    p += 1
    head.append(s[p:])

df.columns = head #### 新しい項目名への置き換え

df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False) #### csv化
```

Comment: pandasのみでもできるのですね。参考になります。ありがとうございます

Comment: `pd.json_normalize([{'target': r['target'], **r['params']} for r in data]).to_csv('data.csv', index=False)` としてもよいかと思います。

Comment: @metropolis さん、複雑すぎずに1行に出来るのは良いですね。